# Running Python Script from AppleScript

Tags: python, applescript

I've installed the cryptography module using pip:

```
pip install cryptography
```

Running a simple test.py file with just an import statement, I can confirm that the module is installed. From terminal:

TEST.PY FILE (just one line):

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
```

RUNNING FROM TERMINAL:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.9 test.py
```

But when I try to run this script from an Apple Script application, the module cannot be found even though I'm using the same version of python:

RUNNING FROM APPLE SCRIPT:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3.9 test.py"
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `do shell script` does not read any configuration files that an interactive shell running in Terminal would - see [Technical Note TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html).

Answer (score 0):

`do shell script` does not set the working directory so either set it at the start of the shell script:

```
do shell script "cd \"$HOME\" && /usr/local/bin/python3.9 test.py"
```

or supply the full path to the `test.py` script:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3.9 " & quoted form of "/Users/foo/test.py"
```

Comment: Why do you effectively do `cd $HOME` when `cd` goes to $HOME anyway? Just do `cd` it's easier and always works.

Comment: My sample code is simplified, but I already am supplying the full path to test.py. It really is  more like your example  (do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3.9 /Users/foo/test.py".) So the working directory shouldn't be relevant. Since I'm giving the full path to the version of python I want to run, shouldn't it run the same as when I provide the full path to python through terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference in execution between **Terminal** and **do shell script** is due to the fact that they use different shells. In order for the modules to be found, the **$PATH** environment variable must contain the path to the **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin** directory.

You can check what **$PATH** contains by running the **echo $PATH** command. At least for me, this variable in **Terminal** contains the path **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin**, but in do shell script it does not. One solution might be to add this path to the $PATH. Note that this addition will be persistent only within the **current do shell script command**.

I haven't tested, try it yourself. Just in case, I also replaced the path to python3.9 with the real one (instead of an alias):

```
set pathEnvironmentVariable to do shell script "echo $PATH"

if pathEnvironmentVariable does not contain "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:" then
    do shell script "
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:$PATH;
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 " & quoted form of "/Users/foo/test.py"
end if
```

Comment: This is incorrect. OP clearly shows their Python is `/usr/local/bin/python3.9` so that is a **locally installed** Python not an Apple-supplied one from `/Library/Frameworks/somewhere` The two are independent.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Python, so I will ask the experts to clarify my answer. Often, when faced with the unknown, I intuitively find the right direction. Now, I feel that the solution to the problem lies in **the way the Python interpreter finds built-in and external modules**. The modules of  installed by user **cryptography** lib is external modules for the Python interpreter.

Comment: **/usr/local/bin/python3.9** is just alias file to original file, located at **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin** folder of local disk.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Terminal and start your normal Python. Then import your package and see where it is being imported from:

```
import cryptography
import sys
# Which Python am I running?
print(sys.executable)
# Where is it looking for modules?
print(sys.path)
# Where was cryptography module found?
print(cryptography.__file__)
```

Now you know how the proper import works.

Then go into the environment it doesn't work, i.e. Applescript and run a script that shows:

- which Python it is running, and
- where it is importing from

---

```
import sys

# Which Python am I using?
print(sys.executable)
# Where does this Python look for modules
print(sys.path)
```